# Keeping beamer in English while supporting Chinese characters

Tags: beamer, unicode, input-encodings, cjk

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{My name (我的名字)}
\date{\today}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the current output:
[image]

I am giving a presentation in English. I only want to support the Chinese names in the `\author{}` field. But now the `\date{}` is also shown in Chinese format.

How can I keep the date in English as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For `ctex` version 1.x:

```
\usepackage[noindent,nocap]{ctex}
```

For `ctex` version 2.x:

```
\usepackage[scheme=plain]{ctex}
```